# Angular Js:How to pull factory data to the controller

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am trying to pull my angular js factory data to my controller,
please have a look if there is any issue.

**factory.js**

```
.factory('History', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

        function history () {

            // angular.extend(SearchOptions.getDefaults(), params, options);
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/res/orders/' + 31536427 + '/history-group'
            })
            .success(function (res) {
            // console.log(res);

            })
            .error(function (err) {
                // TODO error handler
                deferred.reject(err);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            history: history
        };
    }]);
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('HistoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'History', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, History) {

      History.history().then(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
          $scope.history = res.body;
          console.log($scope.history);

        }, function(err) {
          // TODO error handler
          console.log(err);

        })
        .finally(function(err) {

        });



  }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the response in the success function in the 'History' factory as below:

```
.success(function (res) {
   // console.log(res);
   deferred.resolve(res);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is you are not resolving the promise after getting the data in the success callback function. Resolve it as shown below in the `.success` callback function :

```
deferred.resolve(res);
```

Few points to improve your code:

1. `$http` service in Angular by default returns a promise. Hence, you don't have to **explicitly construct a `promise` using `$q`** which is an **anti pattern** ([**Deferred anti-pattern**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)). Just returning `$http` object from the service itself will do the
   job. Doing `return $http()` is equivalent to `return deferred.promise()` in your code.
2. **`.success` and `.error` callbacks are deprecated** in the latest version(1.6) of `AngularJs` ([**Deprecation Notice**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)). The disadvantage of using these is that they are not chainable as they ignore return values. Hence, it is better to use `.then` instead.

Applying above changes, your service can be refactored to below :

```
.factory('History', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function history () {
        return $http({
                     method: 'GET',
                     url: '/res/orders/' + 31536427 + '/history-group'
               })
               .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
     }

   function successCalback (res) {
         return res;
   }

   function errorCalback (err) {
         return err;
   }

    return {
        history: history
    };
}]);
```